# Event registration confirmation page print doesn't work

Tags: civievent, confirmation, printing

After someone registers for an event, a confirmation page is displayed. Some users want to print the page even though a confirmation email is sent. However, the print doesn't work. The page heading is printed and nothing else, even though the correct confirmation info is displayed on the screen. Neither printing using the print icon nor the browser print work. Is there something else that needs to be configured within civi for the print to work?

We're using Wordpress 4.9.9 and Civi 5.4.1

Comment: It sounds like a print css file/module might be interfering with it? Often times those are set to remove major portions of the page and only include certain parts. So it may be stopping those from printing? I just tried it in my install (which is a Drupal one), and its print ability worked fine. Do you happen to have a link we can test?